# Sample EMV tag 91 Values

Tags: payment-gateway, icc, emv

Anyone have knowledge on EMV tags and provide  EMV tag Format and Sample value for  Tag 91- Issuer Authentication Data and Issuer Script Template 1 and 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Issuer Authentication Data are represented using EMV Tag 91 in BER-TLV format.
For more details please check EMV Book 3 (A1 Data Elements by Name)
[image]

example: TLV [910ABCF266A64FF136630010] 
TAG Issuer Authentication Data -> 91 
LEN -> 0A (10 DEC) 
VALUE -> BC F2 66 A6 4F F1 36 63 00 10

Using the same way Issuer Script Template 1 is represented using EMV tag 71 and Issuer Script Template 2 is represented using EMV tag 72.
[image]

example: TLV [72127210860E84DA00CB0910230E1B119D26C2DA] 
TAG Issuer Script Template 2 -> 72 
LEN ->12 (18 DEC)
VALUE->72 10 86 0E 84 DA 00 CB 09 10 23 0E 1B 11 9D 26 C2 DA

Answer (score 2):

Sample values for tag 91 are irrelevant. The contents of tag 91 are defined by the issuer (Visa, Amex, MC, etc.) and can contain anything they want to put in there (subject, of course, to the tag maximum size). The tag should be passed verbatim to the card for it to process.